# Why is this bit of javascript making my checkboxes difficult to check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

My app has a form which uses checkboxes to sort results by type and area. There are 2 fieldsets, one for the types and one for the areas.

The area checkboxes are linked to areas of an imagemap so it too can be used to select multiple areas to sort by.

I have this javascript:

*This links the area checkboxes and the areas of the imagemap so they both act as form inputs*

```
    var $area = $('area');
    $area.click(function(){
        var $checkbox = $('#' + $(this).data("areanum"));
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked')).button('refresh');
    });
    $('label').click(function () {
        $area.filter('[data-areanum="' + $(this).attr('for') + '"]').trigger('click');
        return true;
    });
```

This breaks the type checkboxes (they won't register as being checked when the form is submitted), unless I change the bit:

```
        $('label').click(function () {
            $area.filter('[data-areanum="' + $(this).attr('for') + '"]').trigger('click');
            return false;
        });
```

to

```
        $('label').click(function () {
            $area.filter('[data-areanum="' + $(this).attr('for') + '"]').trigger('click');
            return true;
        });
```

(changed the last line to return true)

But this makes the checkboxes difficult to select, they respond to a single click if the tick area is clicked but only respond to a double click if the checkbox label is clicked.

I hope this makes sense, if any clarification is needed I'll try to word the problem better.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you post a relevant functional example on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the `label` `click` handler at all because you are just toggling the `checkbox` `checked` property by triggering the area `click` handler which will be taken care by label's default behavior itself when it's `for` attribute is set to the `checkbox` id.